# "Is in" condition in GAWK

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

I'm doing a task with Linux terminal and GAWK, and the objective is to extract a list of regular expressions and make a counter of the genes associated with this expression.

I've been able to set a GAWK expression to do this for every regular expression, but I have to run it for every expression of the list.

Is there any way to set a condition like this: If (RegExp is in RegExpList) i++1?

Comment: Your current solution is the wrong approach. If you post a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you. also gawk is just one flavor of awk, if you have an awk question then tag it with awk, not just gawk since far fewer people look at questions with a gawk tag than awk which is why no-one corrected you before now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare RegExpList as an array:

```
RegExpList["RegExp"] = 1;
```

and then use this statement:

```
if(c in RegExpList){do something;}
```

If `c` is `RegExp`, the condition will be true.

See the [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Reference-to-Elements.html#Reference-to-Elements) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It actually makes sense. The problem now is how do I do this  from a file input.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{i=0}
{while ((getline line < "regexpinput.txt") !=FN) RegExpList[line]=1;
if ($4 in RegExpList) i++1}
END{print i}' tabular_file.txt
```

Thanks @nopasara for the help.

Comment: That is using getline incorrectly (will spin off into an infinite loop on some failures - see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) and is reading the whole of the regexp file for every line of the tabular file and is doing a string comparison instead of a regexp comparison and idk what `i++1` will be interpreted as but it's wrong. So whatever it is you do want to do, this isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are this is the right approach:

```
awk '
NR==FNR{ re = (NR>1 ? re "|" : "") "(" $0 ")"; next }
$0 ~ re { cnt++ }
END { print cnt+0 }
' regexpinput.txt tabular_file.txt
```

but if you post a MCVE we'll know for sure.